# Routes with different controllers but same action name fails to produce wanted urls

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to set up a API for my MVC web app that will have a lot of routes but much of the same part for each one.  Basically a CRUD for each area.  I am also setting it up to be version-able.  I have set up two controllers each with a simple action to get started and receive a conflict right off the bat.  The error I get is

I am after these urls

- https://foo.bar/aim/v1/contacts/delete/11111
- https://foo.bar/aim/v1/locations/delete/11111
- and so on

The MVC will let you have a

- https://foo.bar/home/index/
- https://foo.bar/contacts/index/
- and so on

So I am looking for a away around needlessly naming things like `contacts_delete` and `locations_delete` producing URLs like

- https://foo.bar/aim/v1/contacts/contacts_delete/11111
- https://foo.bar/aim/v1/locations/locations_delete/11111
- and so on

  ***(which is in the observation of the root issue provided in the comments and below anwsers like `Route names must be unique. You cannot have two different routes named delete. Use deleteLocation and deleteContact instead.`)***

I may as well just do `https://foo.bar/aim/v1/contacts_delete/11111` but that seems so senseless to me.  If the MVC can do it, i have to believe that there is a way to make this happen.

**The error I get is:**

> Attribute routes with the same name 'delete' must have the same template:
>
> Action: 'rest.fais.foo.edu.Controllers.aimContactsController.delete (rest.fais.foo.edu)' - Template: 'aim/v1/contacts/delete/{id}'
>
> Action: 'rest.fais.foo.edu.Controllers.aimLocationsController.delete (rest.fais.foo.edu)' - Template: 'aim/v1/locations/delete/{id}'

**For the controllers I have set up**

```
[EnableCors("SubDomains")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("aim/v1/contacts/[action]")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(errorJson), 500)]
public class aimContactsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;
    private readonly AimDbContext _aim_context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public aimContactsController(IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment,
        AimDbContext aim_context,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _aim_context = aim_context;
    }



    [HttpPost("{id}", Name = "delete")]
    public IActionResult delete(string id)
    {

        return Json(new
        {
            results = "deleted"
        });
    }

}


[EnableCors("SubDomains")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("aim/v1/locations/[action]")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(errorJson), 500)]
public class aimLocationsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;
    private readonly AimDbContext _aim_context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public aimLocationsController(IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment,
        AimDbContext aim_context,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _aim_context = aim_context;
    }



    [HttpPost("{id}", Name = "delete")]
    public IActionResult delete(string id)
    {

        return Json(new
        {
            results = "deleted"
        });
    }

}
```

For the **Startup.cs** I have

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        //RolesData.SeedRoles(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //app.UseResponseCompression();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        app.UseSession();

        // custom Authentication Middleware
        app.UseWhen(x => (x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/aim_write", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/rms", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
        builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
        });

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            //c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/v1/wsu_restful.json", "v1.0.0");swagger
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1.0.0");
        });


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "javascript",
                template: "javascript/{action}.js",
                defaults: new { controller = "mainline" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AIMApi",
                template: "aim/v1/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "aim" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AIMContactsApi",
                template: "aim/v1/contacts/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "aimContactsController" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AIMLocationsApi",
                template: "aim/v1/locations/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "aimLocationsController" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RMSApi",
                template: "{controller=rms}/v1/{action}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

What I can't seem to google out the answer how to work around this.  I want to fix the immediate issue, but any suggests are welcomed.

Comment: Route names must be unique. You cannot have two different routes named `delete`. Use `deleteLocation` and `deleteContact` instead.

Comment: oh there has to be some other way then no way?  I mean what is the point of defining the controller, doing the route template or anything of that lol.  Custom middelwear maybe?  Just seems like a major mistake to have a router that can't tell the difference between one action on a controller and another.  At that, who can you have a `Index` on all the different MVC controllers?

Comment: Please, don't force tags into questions, it won't make your question be answered faster

Comment: Basically i cannot understand why you have attribute routing when you have the exact same routes on your startup.cs ? Also on your startup.cs the AIMApi route must go after the AIMLocationsApi

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos it is due to it not functioning "correctly"/as expected there.

Comment: @Tseng duly noted, it wasn't malicious

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Both your routes are named the same, this cannot work in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I'm not talking about the methods naming, but about routes naming. You called both your routes with the same identifier `Name = "delete"` inside the `HttpPost` attribute. Route names in MVC uniquely identifies a route template.

From what I can see you do not really need to identify your routes, but only to distinguish different URIs. For this reason you may freely remove the `Name` property of `HttpPost` attribute on your action methods. This should be enough for ASP.NET Core router to match your action methods.

If you, instead, what to revert using only attribute routing you better change your controller to the following:

```
// other code omitted for clarity
[Route("aim/v1/contacts/")]
public class aimContactsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("delete/{id}")]
    public IActionResult delete(string id)
    {
        // omitted ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that the name has to be the different, but how do I get a different url I guess would be the question.  Each time I change the name, the url changes with it.  Most systems don't couple that hard to the URL and if they do need that "slug"/"alias" that there is a URL mapping that will bridge that gap.  I would figured that then, maybe there was a way to do a middleware solution if there is not one built in.

Comment: If you just need different URIs (and not routes) why don't you just remove the `Name` property entirely along with the `[action]` token from the Controller `Route` attribute, and specify the relative url inside the `HttpPost` attribute? Something like this: `[HttpPost("delete/{id}")]`

Comment: So removing the `name=""` attribute take care of part of the answer, the other was as @NickPolideropoulos stated that the order was also off, and the `AIMApi` route must go after the `AIMLocationsApi`.  If you could edit your answer to include that I think we have a solution here.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Amazing that the "Add Controller" wizard still has this bug years later in 2020. I just added my second controller and hit this straight away, in a brand new ASP.NET Core project using all the latest kit. Code would no longer run, immediately started throwing this exception. MS if you're reading this, please stop adding the duplicate `name=` attribute!

Comment: The routes are _not_ named the same! One is `aim/v1/contacts/delete` and the other is `aim/v1/locations/delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is:

```
// other solution
[Route("aim/v1/contacts/[Action]")]
public class aimContactsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("{id}")]
    public IActionResult delete(string id)
    {
        // omitted ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we pass [Action] name dynamically? can you please add some sample code

Comment: Yes, you can pass the action dynamically. Now I put a code example

Answer (score 0):

Example with Action name dynamically:

```
[Route("api/{lang}/[controller]/[Action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SpatiaController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ISpatialService _service;
        private readonly ILogger<SpatialController> _logger;

        public SpatialUnitsIGMEController(ILogger<SpatialController> logger, ISpatialService service) 
        {
            _service = service;
            _logger = logger;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<ItemDto>>> Get50k(string lang)
        {
            var result = await _service.GetAll50k(lang);
            return Ok(result);
        }

        [HttpGet("{name}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ItemDto>> Get50k(string lang, string name)
        {
            var result = await _service.Get50k(lang, name);
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
```

To call these endpoints the following calls would be used:

https://example.domain.com/api/en/spatial/get50k --> we get all the data in English

https://example.domain.com/api/en/spatial/get50k/madrid --> we obtain the data of madrid in english

https://example.domain.com/api/es/spatial/get50k/madrid --> we obtain the data of madrid in spanish

(using the action and language in the route)

Comment: Um, you have restated what is in here already my friend.  2 times now at that. And it's not really relative to the issue asked as well as.  I asked why I was getting it more routes, not that the actions weren't working, or that the param.  The other anwsers.  are close to he real aweser is.

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry if because of my poor English level I didn't quite understand the question.

What I tried in my first answer was to complete Federico Dipuma's answer, providing another way to do the same but more comfortable since it saves writing the action.

Then Good Samaritan asked me for an example of what that code would look like and what I did was respond to him.

I repeat that I am sorry if I did not interpret the question correctly, but I believe that there is another solution to the explanation marked as correct. Thank you and greetings.